# PHP loop logic confusion: How to do blank appending while going through the arrays in the proper spot?

Tags: php, html, datatables

I have three arrays, one holds the values that are uniquetaxids, one is the current taxes associated to the product, and the last array holds the details for all the taxes including the tax values and the names.

I can't figure out the logic behind how to do blank appending while going through the arrays in the proper spot.

```
 $("#productLiting").append("<tr><td>{{$values->product_quantity}}</td><td>{{$values->product_name}}</td>" + '<?php  
        $taxesarray = array();
        $taxesid = explode(",",$values->taxesid,-1);
        foreach ($taxesid as $k){
          foreach ($uniquetaxarray as $unique){
                if ($k != $unique) {
                  echo "<td></td>";
                }
                else {
                    foreach($taxlist as $tax=> $taxes) {
                      if($k == $taxes->id) {
                       echo "<td> {{$taxes->tax}} </td>";
                      }
                    }
                 }
              }
          }                

?>' + "<td>{{$values->products_baseamount}}</td><td>{{$values->products_total}}</td></tr>");
```

This is the code I have currently,

`$uniquetaxarray` holds the unique tax IDs that exist for this invoice
`$taxesid` holds the array which is created from the database pull which holds the taxes associated to the product.
`$taxlist` holds all the taxes available that a product can have.

I can't figure out how to set up the logic so it could append blank `<td>`'s for a product that doesn't have the certain tax associated.

Example values for the array

```
$taxesid holds tax id for the prodct, product1: {no taxes} product 2: {1,2} product 3{1,2} product4 {1,3}
$uniquetaxarray holds the unique values that are available; {1,2,3}
$taxlist : {id:1, tax: GST, taxvalues: 12}, {id:2,tax:Sales Tax, taxvalues:15}, {id:3, tax:HST, taxvalues:10}
```

So for this particular example, `cardtestingnew` has no tax values,`vnktest` has 1,2 ; `product1` has 1,2 ; `water2` has 1,3.
[image]

In this example it should append 3 empty `<td>`'s for `cardtestingnew` , 1 empty `<td>` for HST section for `vnktest`, and `product1`, and it should append an empty `<td>` for GST for `water2`.

Comment: Is there a max number of possible taxes?  Seems it would be much easier to simply fill in a template; and if no value exists for a particular tax, then it obviously would not stick in a value. Also, why use php to fill javascript to build html? you could just use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of whether your tax cell has been printed, and if not, print a blank cell:

```php
foreach ($taxesid as $k){
    foreach ($uniquetaxarray as $unique){
        if ($k != $unique) {
             echo "<td></td>";
        }
        else {
            $taxPrinted = false; // stores whether a tax cell has been printed
            foreach($taxlist as $tax=> $taxes) {
                if($k == $taxes->id) {
                    echo "<td> {{$taxes->tax}} </td>";
                    $taxPrinted = true; // stores that a tax cell was printed
                }
            }

            if(!$taxPrinted) { // if a tax cell wasn't printed, print a blank one
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something different:

```
// Create taxes details map first so it could be referenced without looping through
$taxlistMap = array(); 
foreach($taxlist as $tax) {
  $taxlistMap[$tax->id] = $tax
}

// Now loop through the list of unique tax ids as you always need a full or empty <td> for each unique tax column  
foreach($uniquetaxarray as $unique) {
  // Now if product has the specific tax add a <td> with tax details
  if(in_array($unique, $taxesid)) {
    echo "<td>". $taxlistMap[$unique]->tax . "</td>"
  }
  // Otherwise empty <td>
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }

}
```

Unfortunately I don't have the data set and html around to test it but I hope you get the idea which is - you have to start looping through the array of unique tax IDs first and then check if product has the tax and populate  elements accordingly.
By the way if `$uniquetaxarray` derived from `$taxlist` then you dong even have to create map array for taxes, just start looping through `$taxlist` array instead of `$uniquetaxarray`.
Hope this helps.